# Sqlite FTS minimal token size

Tags: sqlite, fts5

How to tell Sqlite FTS5 to only index tokens over a certain length ?

The `'prefix=n'` option is close but serves prefix-indexing.
The `'tokenize'` options don't seem to offer this.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE words USING fts5 (  
    title  
    ,content = books  
    ,content_rowid = id  
    ,tokenize = "unicode61 tokenchars '-'"  
);
```

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own tokenizer.

Comment: Damn.. that would be overkill.  I can't believe this simple option is missing.